# Using an int for an id using Doctrine ODM for MongoDB in Zend

Tags: mongodb, zend-framework2, doctrine-odm

I am trying to use a int as my _id, and am wondering what type I need to use for that.  When I use Id, it converts it to a MongoID.  It seems like there is an IntIdType in the code, but no annotation and am not sure how this gets used.

```
class Page implements InputFilterAwareInterface
{

/** @ODM\Id */
private $_id;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I received an email back from the guy who contributed the code and he explained what I had to do.  The code should look like this to work:

```
class Page implements InputFilterAwareInterface
{

/** @ODM\Id(strategy="INCREMENT") */
private $_id;

}
```

Hopefully they should update their documentation soon.  Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 1):

There is [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers) for ODM identifiers.

According to that documentation you need to describe your Id as:

```
class Page implements InputFilterAwareInterface
{

    /** @ODM\Id(strategy="NONE", type="int") */
    private $_id;

}
```